# How do I write a haskell function which duplicates every occurrence of a given character in a string

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

import Data.STRef
import Data.Char

main = do
         let x = dup 'a' "the cat in the hat has a fat head"
         putStrLn $ show $ x
```

This is what I have so far, I don't know where to go form here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I may be mistaken, but this just looks like a problem statement - not even a test case, let alone an attempt. Why don't you try solving this on your own and see where you get stuck, then asking about _that_? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:` when writing function to work with list

- `x:xs` to pattern match a list to head `x` and tail `xs`
- `x:xs` to build a list from `x` and `xs`

There are many way to write `dup` function , this is my quick solution using guard `|`

```
dup :: Char -> String -> String
dup c [] = []
dup c (x:xs)
  | c == x    =  x:x:dup c xs
  | otherwise =  x:dup c xs

main = do 
  let x = dup 'a' "the cat in the hat has a fat head"
  putStrLn x
```

give

```
the caat in the haat haas aa faat heaad
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using list comprehension.

```
dup :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
dup c string = [ ss | s <- string, ss <- if c == s then [c] ++ [s] else [s]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do this ;), e.g.

```
dup :: Char -> String -> String
dup charToDup s = concatMap dupC s
  where dupC c = if c == charToDup then replicate 2 c
                 else [c]
```